# Ubuntu touch on Nexus 4 fails to boot

Tags: boot, ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

Last week I tried Ubuntu Touch on my Nexus 4, and it was easy to install en to recover to android. So today I wanted to show the preview to some friends, and something has gone very wrong.

---

Current status:

On boot I get a black screen

bootloader does work (volume down + power on)

Recovery mode gives me black screen

---

What I have done:

1 Updated my system (sudo apt-get update)

2 Installed (sudo phablet-flash -b)

After that my phone hang on the Google logo while booting.
Started recovery mode and started poking around. <- probably my first mistake.

3 Tried to reinstall (sudo phablet-flash -b) but didn't work. Gave error that I should use -d.

4 Tried reinstall with (phablet-flash -d grouper -b).

---

Can someone help me out on getting android back on my phone, because I don't know what to do.
"adb devices" tells me that there are no devices attached, so I really dont know how to reinstall or recover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for your information. In the [Release Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/ReleaseNotes), Device Specific Issues, there is a paragraph for the Nexus4

> In rare circumstances, the Nexus4 may get into a state where it may
>   not boot at all after the battery is drained (even into recovery). If
>   this happens, the only way to restore it is to disassemble the back of
>   the phone and unplug/plug the battery connector. See [Power Consumption](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/ReleaseNotes#PowerConsumption)
>   to learn how to avoid discharging the phone completely.

Answer (score 2):

### Some obvious issues:

**(1.)** The command **`sudo apt-get update`** needs to be followed by **`sudo apt-get upgrade`**. This will likely load a newer **phablet-flash** version.

Or combine into:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

**(2.)** The command **`phablet-flash -d grouper -b`** will likely *brick* your Nexus 4 (mako). The 'grouper' tag is for 'Nexus 7' ..

---

To recover:

Put the device in 'Recovery Mode', and then run:

```
phablet-flash -d mako -b
```

---

***IF that fails, revert to factory / Android setup.***

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install

Look for: 'Restoring Android'

( *You may also need to put phone into 'Recovery Mode' for this to work.* )